# React Native Maps Overlay

Tags: ios, react-native

Has anyone used the overlay property with react-native-maps? I am trying to create a line that follows my current location but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is my code

```
    <MapView
      style={styles.map}
      region= {{
        latitude: this.state.currentLatLng.latitude,
        longitude: this.state.currentLatLng.longitude,
        latitudeDelta: .007,
        longitudeDelta: .007,
      }}
      mapType='satellite'
      showsUserLocation={true}
      followUserLocation={false}
      overlays={[{
        coordinates: this.state.routeCoordinates,
        strokeColor: '#19B5FE',
        lineWidth: 10,
      }]}
      />
```